# Free space of Android storage - File.getFreeSpace() vs StatFs

Tags: android, android-file, android-storage

I'm trying to understand the difference between these two methods to get free space of a storage on Android devices:

**First method (Android SDK)**

```
val stats = StatFs(file.absolutePath)
val freespace = stats.availableBlocksLong * stats.blockSizeLong
```

**Second method (Java)**

```
val freespace = File.getFreeSpace(file)
```

The second method always returns a little bigger value than the first method. Why so?

**Update**:

It seems we can use `File.getUsableSpace()` instead of `File.getFreeSpace(file)` to get the same result as with `StatFs`

So it seems there is no point to use `StatFs` if we can just get the free space easily from file by using `getUsableSpace` method

Answer (score 0):

**First Method - StatFs() :**

It retrieves overall information about the space on a filesystem. This is a wrapper for Unix statvfs().

**Second Method - File.getFreeSpace(file):**

The getFreeSpace() function is a part of File class in Java. This function returns the unallocated size of the partition denoted by the abstract path name, if the path name does not exist then it returns 0L. This function gives a hint of the unallocated space of the partition but does not give any guarantee that the exact number of bytes are free.